# Malformed Apache requests

Tags: apache

I am facing an issue where the Apache requests are malformed and is causing unusual behavior with the application. We have Webcache servers in front of Apache webservers. The requests in the Webcache servers are fine but they end malformed at Apache webservers.

Request in Webcache access log: Request is well formed with GET or POST (xx.xx.xx.xx - - [Timestamp] "GET /abc/def.htm HTTP/1.1" 501 559 "referrer URL" "browser/5.0 (Linux;
U; Android 4.2.2; locale; SM-G386F Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 " "" 0.009315)

Corresponding request at Apache webserver is malformed as
yy.yy.yy.yy xx.xx.xx.xx - - [timestamp] "jumbled_characters_GET /abc/def.htm HTTP/1.1" 501 990 "referrer URL" "-"

Some characters are getting added before the actual request ("GET /abc/def.htm HTTP/1.1") and such requests are not getting blocked/ handled at Apache but are making it to the Application servers that are behind the webserver.

Apache version: Apache/2.2.27
Webcache: Oracle 11g
OS: SunOS

Please let me know if anyone has faced such an issue and how can this be handled.

Thanks

Comment: Your examples of the "request in webcache access log" and "request at apache websserver" are exactly the same.  So it's not clear what the problem is.  Secondly, you don't say what the webcache software is: this could well be relevant

Comment: Thanks Vorsprung. We are using Oracle Webcache. Requests look like the below:-
Webcache request - "GET /abc/def.htm HTTP/1.1"
Apache request - "<jumbled_characters>GET /abc/def.htm HTTP/1.1"